# Percentage breakdown 1-100 rating question data (1 Strongly Disagree - 100 Strongly Agree)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to know what percentage of people that agree or strongly agree with a 1-100 rating scale in Python. I can use .describe() but it won't tell me what percentage of people chose 60 or higher.

The question is a statement and respondents must click 1 (Strongly Disagree) to 100 (Strongly Agree).

How do I get the percentage breakdown for respondents that said 60 or higher?

Thank you!

[image: Density Distribution]

[image: group_by & size]

Comment: Don't you just sum up the number of people who responded with 60 or above and divide the sum with the total number of people responded?

Comment: I *assume* you are using Pandas and that the `Q2` you are working with here is a `DataFrame`. You should explicitly say these things and tag your question accordingly (I edited the tags already). More importantly, you should *show actual code with context* - don't just show us how you use `Q2`, but show us how it gets a value. Even more importantly, [don't use images to show us textual data](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). Instead, copy and paste the output and [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) it properly.

Comment: Thank you Karl for the advise. Will take it on board for my next question. Much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do this is to make a new column and take the mean:

```py
Q2['newcol'] = Q2['I fully enjoy ...'] >= 60
print(Q2['newcol'].mean())
```

That should give you the correct fraction.

The idea here is that we translate the response into a 0 or 1 binary value; the mean of this data is then the sum of those values divided by the count, which is equal to the *number of 1s* divided by the count, i.e. the fraction of people who gave a matching (i.e., `>= 60`) answer.

Comment: Thank you so much @Tanner Eastmond! That is exactly what.I needed to do. Much appreciated :-)